# Find last child class from DLLs with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have `WPF` application which i need to upgrade. Last version of that app used configuration XML file which contains paths to all DLLs which this app needs. Now with upgrade, one of the main requirements are to get rid of configuration file, and let `WPF` app dynamically get all necessary `DLLs` (like Datareader DLL for populating `treeview` etc).
I developped a logic for reading DLLs in current assembly (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`), filtering and other stuff. But i came across another problem.
Lets say that i have structure like this.

```
Interface IDataReader that all datareaders class implements.
DLL -> BaseDataReader.dll  
       BaseDataReader
DLL -> ChildDataReader.dll : BaseDataReader.dll 
       ChildDataReader1 : BaseDataReader
DLL -> ChildDataReader2.dll : ChildDataReader (base class inside ChildDataReader.dll).
       ChildDataReader2 : ChildDataReader1
```

I have other data readers too, so this is one of situations. I filtered `DLLs` based on interface (`IDataReader`) and get `DLLs` (from example) but i need always last child in this chain.

So my questions is this possible to do such a thing in c#? I need to this works in every situations, for example if i have only BaseDataReader.dll i will is it, and so on.

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: pretty old article, but contains code for inspecting assemblies and loading types that meet given criteria. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29171/Implementing-the-Factory-Pattern-Part-1-of-2-or-3